# SUM ignore WHERE but not GROUP BY

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sum

I have two tables, `adverts` and `advertsitems`. These tables got a one (`adverts`) to many (`advertsitems`) relation. I’m building this query dynamically, so that’s why I use `WHERE 1=1` to make it easier to add new conditions.

I have the following query

```
  SELECT a.title AS adtitle, 
         a.id AS adid, 
         a.price, 
         a.image AS image, 
         a.description, 
         SUM(ai.quantity) as quantity, 
         a.shipping, 
         a.customs, 
         a.createdate
    FROM adverts a
           LEFT JOIN advertsitems ai 
                     ON a.id = ai.advertid
   WHERE 1=1 
     AND ai.country LIKE '%AF%'
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

The result of `SUM(ai.quantity)` is 2 in this case. If I remove the `WHERE` condition `ai.country LIKE`, the result is 6. I would like to retreive both values in two seperated columns. So basically I want a `SUM` that ignores the `WHERE` but *not* the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT a.title AS adtitle, a.id AS adid, a.price, a.image AS image, a.description,
       SUM(ai.quantity) as totalquantity,
       SUM(case when ai.country LIKE '%AF%' then quantity else 0 end) as AFquantity
      a.shipping, a.customs, a.createdate, ai.country
FROM adverts a LEFT JOIN
     advertsitems ai
     ON a.id = ai.advertid
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

If you actually want to filter by country, then use a `having` clause.  It will do the filtering *after* the aggregation:

```
SELECT a.title AS adtitle, a.id AS adid, a.price, a.image AS image, a.description,
       SUM(ai.quantity) as totalquantity,
       SUM(case when ai.country LIKE '%AF%' then quantity else 0 end) as AFquantity
      a.shipping, a.customs, a.createdate
FROM adverts a LEFT JOIN
     advertsitems ai
     ON a.id = ai.advertid
WHERE 1=1 
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING ai.country LIKE '%AF%'
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

Comment: Hey, thanks (again) for your (quick) reply. If I run your query I get all the results on adverts but I only want adverts whith a 'ai.country LIKE' match. If I add 'ai.country LIKE' to the query I get same results both colums totalquantity and afquantity are 2.

Comment: Thanks! You are a genius :D I only had to add ai.country to the SELECT else i get 'unknown column in having clause'.